# Google Analytics - How can I display the % of total events that have a metric of Value >= X?

Tags: google-analytics

I'm using Universal Google Analytics (UA).

If I have a given event with Event Action 'MyCustomEvent', this event has a custom metric reported with it called 'MyCustomMetric'.

This metric can be an positive integer value, with 0 being allowed and most common.

What I want is a report that shows me what percentage of instances of the 'MyCustomEvent' had an value of 'MyCustomMetric' bigger than 0 (or greater than some desired value).

I feel this should be really simple but I'm struggling to wrap my head around custom reports and getting this data displayed.

I tried looking at custom Calculated Metrics to see if I could just have a TRUE/FALSE calculation based on the metric value (then I could have a report with the total count of TRUE), but it doesn't support boolean values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a segment on your report. Under the section Conditions just select the MyCustomMetric and it will grant you the possibility to get only positive values.

You will get all sessions (or hit) for which MyCustomMetric is positive.